# How to import/export all Hbase tables at a time?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

```
$ bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export <tablename> <outputdir> [<versions> [<starttime> [<endtime>]]]
```

above command is useful for export only single table but it is very time consuming so I want to export all tables at time so is there any command which export all tables at a time??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import/Export work on per-table basis. Alternatively, you could use Hadoop’s **distcp** command to copy the whole **/hbase** directory from one HDFS cluster to the other. However, this can leave your data in an inconsistent state, so it should be avoided.

I would like to point out to a backup tool developed by folks at Mozilla which they say eliminates the limitations of distcp. See their [***post***](http://blog.mozilla.org/data/2011/02/04/migrating-hbase-in-the-trenches/) for more details.

Comment: For export - copyFromLocal and for import- copyToLocal command also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got my question answer:

For export table use copyFromLocal command - It copies local \hbase directory
For import table use copyToLocal command -It pastes in local \hbase directory.